# Way to show and hide content on different screens in HTML

Tags: javascript, css, html

The short question:
I have a simple monitor and a projector, both should show the same browser window with the same page loaded, but with some different content for each of them. Is there any way to achive this with css or js (or maybe with a specific browser extension)?

Longer explanation:
I want to build a little presentation plugin with js and css, and the biggest presentation programs all have a timer on the screen, but not on the projector. This feature is something I want to realise. Notes or something like that could also be added, but all that requires different content on different screens/projectors, so I need a solution for that. For this even a browser extension would be useful because I only want the plugin for myself.
So, do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

You can specify different *media*. Like this:

```
@media projection{
//projection css
}

@media screen{
//screen css
}
```

Then, obviously, the projection ones will apply to *projection* media, like slides, projectors, etc, and the screen stuff will only apply to a computer screen. Now, you may want to toy around with the `projection` css, as I've never actually tested it. But you could easily get away with just using the `screen` stuff to set certain stuff to `display:block;`, while it is `display:none;` otherwise.

Comment: This is a genuine question (as I've never heard of `@media projection` before, but looking on [w3.org](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/media.html#media-types) I can see it is valid)... how would it work when the projector is displaying the same "monitor"?  Will the browser actually render differently for the same source onto two different output channels?

Comment: @freefaller Yeah, the browser will detect what kind of media it is rendering to and render the page differently. I rarely use it myself, though.

Comment: Wow - I'm surprised, I would never have thought that a single browser window would be rendered twice. Thanks for the information, useful to know... hope it's what the OP is after

Comment: I am trying it out at the moment... Just have to configure my projector

Comment: @freefaller it has to be rendered every time it gets displayed somewhere :) Digitally displayed, at least.

Comment: I guess you're right - I always thought the browser would render once, and then that would be sent to the monitor AND the projector (if the projector was mirroring the monitor). Never thought about the fact that it would actually render once for the monitor and then again for the projector.  You learn something new everyday, if you're not careful  ;-)

Comment: Doubtful: Is there really a browser out there that creates a second instance of the page and keeps care of rendering it to screen and projector at the same time?  This is apparently necessary if you want Javascript code take action based on the media context to display the clock on "screen" but not "projection". @DerWaldschrat I'm curious of your research.

Comment: Well, first I have to resolve the problem of the correct display mode..., cloning is not that good if projector has 800x600 and display 1920x1080

Comment: With cloning mode it does not work, it just displays the screen content on both
And the extension mode is senseless, so it seams not possible if you cannot recognize the display

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use media queries for that in CSS3.

See thinkvitamin.com for example, resize your window and see how it is arranging the UI according to the screen size.

You can also hide or show divs at a particular screen resolution, but I think that this will work only in CSS3.